# Create imagefield with maximum number of values programmatically

Tags: forms, media

I've created an imagefield in my own module, like this:

```
$form['heading_img'] = array(
    '#type' => 'media',
    '#title' => t('Heading image'),
    '#default_value' => isset($content['settings']['heading_img']) ? $content['settings']['heading_img'] : '',
    '#theme' => 'media_widget',
    '#media_options' => array(
      'global' => array(
        'types' => array('image'),
        'schemes' => array(
          'public' => 'public',
        ),
        'file_extensions' => 'png gif jpg jpeg',
        'min_resolution' => '1920x550',
        'max_filesize' => '750 KB',
        'uri_scheme' => 'public',
      ),
    ),
);
```

Sometimes I need more heading images. Is it possible to make this field unlimited?

So you could click on a button: Add an other image. Something like [this](https://www.drupal.org/files/cardinality-unlimited_1.png).

Answer (score 0):

When scanning though the [field definition](http://cgit.drupalcode.org/media/tree/includes/media.fields.inc) of the media fields, you'll notice the `multiselect` property on line 118. Which gets the value of `$multiselect` from line 103:

```
$multiselect = ($field['cardinality'] > 1 || $field['cardinality'] == FIELD_CARDINALITY_UNLIMITED);
```

So in your definition you could try adding this multiselect property with an integer value (eg. 5 to allow 0-5 images), or `FIELD_CARDINALITY_UNLIMITED`.

```
$form['heading_img'] = array(
    '#type' => 'media',
    '#title' => t('Heading image'),
    '#default_value' => isset($content['settings']['heading_img']) ? $content['settings']['heading_img'] : '',
    '#theme' => 'media_widget',
    '#media_options' => array(
      'global' => array(
        'types' => array('image'),
        'schemes' => array(
          'public' => 'public',
        ),
        'file_extensions' => 'png gif jpg jpeg',
        'min_resolution' => '1920x550',
        'max_filesize' => '750 KB',
        'uri_scheme' => 'public',
        'multiselect' => FIELD_CARDINALITY_UNLIMITED
      ),
    ),
);
```

Comment: I saw this, but this is only for uploading images. I can't select multiple images in a specific field, just one image.

Comment: Then you must create multiple form fields with the same definition. So you'll end up with `$form['heading_img'], $form['heading_img2'], $form['heading_img3']` and so on. You can do this hardcoded, or using AJAX (see the [ajax_example](http://cgit.drupalcode.org/examples/tree/ajax_example?h=7.x-1.x) in the [examples project](http://drupal.org/project/examples)). But wouldn't it be easier to create a content type or an [entityform](https://www.drupal.org/project/entityform) for this?

Comment: This is a part of a custom module, I can't create a content type or entityform for this.